C++: array types and new
I'm learning C++.  The following program looks nice and generic:
typedef some_type T;
int main() {
  T* p = new T;
}

And it indeed works for non-array types like int, etc.  However, if I try typedef int T[2]; it breaks with the error :

cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[2]'.

What's the logic here?  Is there anything I could do to new to make it return an object of the correct (for this pointer) type?
typedef int T[2];
int main() {
  T* p = new ???;
}

FWIW, new int[2] doesn't work either.  Maybe I'm missing some syntax here, the general idea would be to allocate an object of type T where type T happens to be an array of two ints.

T* is actually int(*)[2]. So the correct syntax would be T* p = new T[2]; .

A side note: in general it's better to use std::array over a raw C array. Creating type aliases is also more straightforward.

Is there anything I could do to new to make it return an object of the correct (for this pointer) type? Answer: T* p = new int[1][2];

Or, if you don't know the size until runtime (say, the size depends on data read when the program is running) then use a resizeable container such as std::vector.   Essentially, it is better to avoid C-style arrays (and direct use of any new expression) as much as possible

It is better to use smart pointers and array or vector instead of c-style pointer and array because you have to care about memory management.

@Mahdy.n even with smart pointers you have to use the correct syntax for new.  And vector isn't appropriate here since they only want one instance of T.

@MarkRansom sure , but if he uses a pointer to vector  with  unique_ptr<vector<int>> or array  than he doesn't need to use  new  and delete.

@Mahdy.n how do you initialize the unique_ptr without new?  That was my point.

@MarkRansom  I certainly don't have as much development experience as you, but
Should we use NEW? I don't think so, we can create a unique pointer to the vector like: using T  = int; for any type of data and  std:: vector<T> vec(size);  and pointer  auto vec_ptr = std::make_unique<std::vector<T>>(vec);  and than use the pointer.

@MarkRansom you are right that even with a unique_ptr there is a new hiding somewhere. But (1) You can use make_unique to clean your code from explicit news altogether (2) you don't have to worry about manual deletes.  Maybe I misunderstood your intention, but don't you agree it is still better ?

@wohlstad yes I agree that eliminating new/delete is a good thing, a local variable is the best when you can get away with it.  But since the question is about new all this side banter is just distracting.

@MarkRansom since the OP mentioned they are studing C++ I thought it could be helpful (in addition to addressing the specific issue). Like you said a local variable would be the best if applicable, and I also mentioned it in my answer below.


Maybe I'm missing some syntax here

First note that T* is actually int(*)[2].
Now, there are two options/answers here:
One valid syntax is:
T* p = new int[2][2];

Or another equivalent valid syntax is:
T* p = new T[2]; //this is also valid in c++


Btw you should use std::array and smart pointers in modern c++.

The other answer already gave the solution for your immediate problem.
But since you mentioned you learn C++, you can find some recommendations below:

As mentioned it is recommended to prefer std::array over raw C arrays (or std::vector for dynamic sized arrays).

Use pointers only if you really need them. Using objects "by value" is better in many cases (and should actually be your default).

If you must use a pointer prefer smart pointers over a raw C ones. They will manage the lifetime of the object automatically for you (when you use new you must remember to eventually match it with a delete).


Here's a short example:
#include <memory>
#include <array>

// T is an alias for the type of std::array<int,2>:
using T = std::array<int,2>;    

int main() {
    // a is an object of type std::array<int,2>:
    T a;    

    // p is a unique_ptr to std::array<int,2>:
    std::unique_ptr<T> p = std::make_unique<T>();   
}

Note the usage of type alias instead of typedef in modern C++.
